# Android MapView Overlay refresh timing

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-animation, android-overlay

I need an overlay that refreshes with 2Hz - for animated [Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay). There is this [second `draw()` method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas,%20com.google.android.maps.MapView,%20boolean,%20long%29) which triggers a redraw when you return `true`.

```
public boolean draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas,
                    MapView mapView,
                    boolean shadow,
                    long when) {
```

This is all working fine, but I need to slow it down that it does not consume that much CPU and battery. - I think the key is this `long when` parameter, but I have problems understanding how to use it (as I get it as a parameter and I see no way to set it). The documentation is not really helping there either.